# How to i put Node.js on my hosting website

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, web-hosting

I'm a little confused on how node.js works on web hosting servers.

Now i understand how it works when i download node.js on my computer, i run files and stuff and the node.js files are on my computer.

What i dont understand is how i run node.js on my web hosting server.

If node.js is a downloadable file, how do i get it to run on my server...

Do i just find the file on my computer that says node.js(or whatever its called) and upload that to my server?

Any clarification on how to run node.js on my server will help.

Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on what your web hosting is. Some don't even provide the ability to run Node code (the free hosting services).

Comment: vps or node webhost is really the easiest ways

Comment: @miparnisari Im using ehost.

Comment: It seems that eHost does not support Node.js: https://support.ehost.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/compatible-technologies

Comment: ehost's main stuff is shared hosting, you can contact their support to see if they will support node, I doubt they will tho. You will need another host most likely unless u have a vps with root access

Comment: @miparnisari Why cant i just upload the node.js files?

Comment: @miparnisari Isnt it just javascript?

Comment: Yes, it's just javascript, but it needs an engine in which to run, it doesn't run in the browser.

Comment: @miparnisari is correct you need the Node.js Platform on your machine your Node.js code won't work without an http server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server is just another computer somewhere running OS like Linux, Windows and others but at large scale. Now Node.js is automatically configured if your web hosting server is a shared server or free plan server like [Heroku](http://heroku.com), an awesome web hosting company with great hosting plan.

You only get to install Node.js on a web hosting server if its a dedicated server like an `Ubuntu Machine on Amazon or Digital Ocean`. I don't think you should bother yourself much. If you want to move your Node.js app from localhost to a web server I encourage you to read heroku documentation or this [scotch.io link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-to-heroku). It is extremely simple.

Comment: Hey thank you, Just one more question, Is it completely free? how do they make money?

Comment: Its completely free. Not sure how they make money. You can check out their pricing for more details https://www.heroku.com/pricing