# How to host react mysql node.js to hosting? || beginner

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

Iam beginner on SWE and now im on learning about hosting..

in my question is..
how to host node.js mysql react.js ? i read that firebase is using NoSql.

My learning project has 2 directory

```
--CRUD
 -server
 -client
```

the frontend is on the client folder. and the backend is on the server folder

Pls help..

Comment: "SWE" -> https://swe.org/ ?

Comment: But does this help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528939/how-to-i-put-node-js-on-my-hosting-website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528939/how-to-i-put-node-js-on-my-hosting-website) ?